# Forward DB requests after a DB move in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I've moved database from one SQL Server instance on a machine to another machine completely.  Is there any way to forward requests to the new server automatically so it doesn't require client config changes?  Keep in mind it's only one DB out of many on the original server so I can't just forward all requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an **[alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190445.aspx)** for your new server that is the name of the old server/instance - but that would forward all requests to the new server.

As far as I know, SQL Server doesn't have a concept of a "database alias" as of yet.

See this [discussion thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/5a1d81fc-ac13-4bef-9a47-2fcd285fab80) on MSDN social about this topic.